# JavaScript Cannot Set Property '0' of undefined (2-dimensional array)

Tags: javascript, arrays, undefined

I know a bunch of people have already asked this, but nothing I have tried has worked. I have been stuck for days.

I suspect it may just be because the thing I am using (code.org) is a pile of flaming garbage, and it uses ES5. If you notice anything wrong, though, please let me know!

```js
function Vector2(x, y)
{
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  
  return this;
}

function Pixel(x, y, darkness)
{
  this.position = Vector2(x, y);
  this.darkness = darkness;
  
  this.rgbDarkness = this.darkness * 255;
  
  return this;
}

function DataTexture2D(offsetX, offsetY, width, height)
{
  this.offset = Vector2(offsetX, offsetY);
  this.size = Vector2(width, height);
  
  this.pixels = [];
  
  for (var x = 0; x < width; x++)
  {
    this.pixels[x] = [];
    for (var y = 0; y < height; y++)
    {
      this.pixels[x][y] = Pixel(x + this.offset.x, y + this.offset.y, 0.5);
    }
  }
  
  return this;
}

var test = DataTexture2D(100, 50, 200, 300);

console.log(test.offset.x);
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @DanielVilas-Boas am trying to make an object that stores an array of greyscale pixels.